# Magento 2 - Configurable product - Get parent product ID from child product ID

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, url

I have a configurable product with two virtual products as children. I have the child product ID. How can I the parent product ID from the child product ID?

I have tried this but it is not working

```
// the $parent is always empty
$parent = $childProduct->getTypeInstance()->getParentIdsByChild($childProductId);
```

Comment: Added the code I have tried.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try following way:

```
$parentIds = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable')
            ->getParentIdsByChild($productId);
$parentId = array_shift($parentIds);
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Get Parent Product from Child Id.**

```
protected $_productloader;
protected $configurable;
protected $grouped;
protected $bundleSelection;

public function __construct(
    ...........................................................
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader,
    \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable $configurable,
    \Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped $grouped,
    \Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Type $bundleSelection,
    ...........................................................
) {
    ...........................................................
    $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
    $this->configurable = $configurable;
    $this->grouped = $grouped;
    $this->bundleSelection = $bundleSelection;
    ...........................................................
}

...........................................................
...........................................................
...........................................................

public function getParentProductData($productData)
{
    $prdData = '';
    $parentProductId = $this->getParentProductId($productData->getEntityId());
    if ($parentProductId) {
        $prdData = $this->_productloader->create()->load($parentProductId);
    } else {
        $prdData = $this->_productloader->create()->load($productData->getEntityId());
    }
    // parent Product Data
    return $prdData;
}

public function getParentProductId($childId)
{
    $parent_id = 0;
    // configurable product
    $product = $this->configurable->getParentIdsByChild($childId);
    if (isset($product[0])) {
        $parent_id = $product[0];
        return $parent_id;
    }
    // group product
    $groupIds = $this->grouped->getParentIdsByChild($childId);
    if (isset($groupIds[0])) {
        $parent_id = $groupIds[0];
        return $parent_id;
    }
    // bundel product
    $budel_id = $this->bundleSelection->getParentIdsByChild($childId);
    if (isset($budel_id[0])) {
        $parent_id = $budel_id[0];
        return $parent_id;
    }
    return $parent_id;
}
```